# how to select a particular string from a column value and assign it to a new column in pandas

Tags: pandas, dictionary, apply

docs = [doc1, doc2, doc 3]

nurses = [nur1, nur2, nur3]

| 1st responder | Associates |
| --- | --- |
| doc1 | nur1, nur2 |
| nur1 | doc1, nur2 |
| nur3 | nur1, nur2, doc2 |
| doc2 | nur2, nur1 |

I want to add a new column 'Doctor' and select the doctor from either '1st responder' or from 'Associates' such that the resultant df is like:

| 1st responder | Associates | Doctor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| doc1 | nur1, nur2 | doc1 |
| nur1 | doc1, nur2 | doc1 |
| nur3 | nur1, nur2, doc2 | doc2 |
| doc2 | nur2, nur1 | doc2 |

Should I use apply/map or is there a vectorised method?

Comment: note: actual lists are names and quite long

Comment: What are the two lists `docs` and `nurses`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the rows `where` 1st responder `isin` the list `docs` and fill the missing values with the `str.extract` on the second column. so

```
df['Doctor'] = (
    df['1st responder']
      .where(lambda x: x.isin(docs), 
             other = df['Associates'].str.extract(pat='('+'|'.join(docs)+')')[0])
)
print(df)
#   1st responder        Associates Doctor
# 0          doc1        nur1, nur2   doc1
# 1          nur1        doc1, nur2   doc1
# 2          nur2  nur3, nur4, doc2   doc2
# 3          doc2              nur4   doc2
```

input used

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '1st responder': ['doc1','nur1','nur2','doc2'],
    'Associates' : ['nur1, nur2', 'doc1, nur2', 'nur3, nur4, doc2', 'nur4']
})
docs = ['doc1','doc2', 'doc3']
```

Comment: Found this code to be more intuitive for me and it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
docs = ['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3']

df['Doctor'] = df.assign(Associates=df['Associates'].str.split(', ')) \
                 .melt(ignore_index=False).explode('value') \
                 .query('value.isin(@docs)').groupby(level=0)['value'].first()
```

Output:

| 1st responder | Associates | Doctor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| doc1 | nur1, nur2 | doc1 |
| nur1 | doc1, nur2 | doc1 |
| nur3 | nur1, nur2, doc2 | doc2 |
| doc2 | nur2, nur1 | doc2 |

Comment: This should work. But I find the code logic to be way over my head. Thanks!!